# Why Does This Code Return A Tuple With 2 Elements?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```py
my_string = "C2H6O"
a = re.findall("((Cl|H|O|C|N)[0-9]*)", my_string)
print(a)
```

The output is `[("C2", "C"), ("H6", "H"), ("O", "O")]`, but I expected `["C2", "H6", "O"]`.

I somewhat understand the tuple, but I feel like nothing in this code causes the second element in the tuple `("C2", "C")`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eTCsHR/1

Answer (score 5):

Because your pattern contains capture groups.

From [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

If you want to get rid of them, use this pattern:

```
r"(?:Cl|H|O|C|N)[0-9]*"
```

It removes the (unneeded) outer capture group completely and uses a non-capturing group for the alpha characters.

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?:Cl|H|O|C|N)[0-9]*", my_string)
['C2', 'H6', 'O']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change your regular expression to:

```
re.findall("([Cl|H|O|C|N][0-9]*)", my_string)
```

You will get what you expect. This removes some of the grouping.

Comment: This is not the expected behaviour -- `[Cl|H|O|C|N]` means "any single occurence of C, l, |, H, O, C or N".

Comment: I think that is the OP's intention.

Comment: I believe the intention here is to match chemical element symbols in molecules.  Your expression will match on `|||393` too, which does not look like a molecule at all.